# Double integration diverges due to the non-Gaussian noise

Tags: mathematical-statistics, numerical-integration

I added Gaussian noise to my input data and then I integrated it twice (I used trapezoidal rule). I was wondering if the the integration itself transform the Gaussian noise to something else. I looked at the probability density function of which is

$$f(x)= \frac {1} {\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{- \frac{1}{2}(\frac{x- \mu}{\sigma})^2}$$

When we integrate the probability density function it's equal to 1 (property of Gaussian distribution). 
$$\int f(x)=1$$
Thus the distribution of the noise is Gaussian.
When we integrated again (double integration) the probability density function is not equal to 1 anymore and it depends on the domain which we integrate it. I was wondering if we can conclude that after the second integration the Gaussian noise is not Gaussian anymore from the fact that the double integration of the probability density function is not 1.

Comment: When we integrate _any_ proper probability density function over its support, it equals unity. It has nothing to do with what distribution is it. Also, the Gaussian/normal distribution is _not_ the only one that has support $(-\infty, \infty)$

Comment: @Alecos: I think the issue at the heart of the matter here is that the whole second part of the question is a non-sequitur. Integrating a function plus noise has little (if anything) to do with integrating the pdf of the noise. The OP seems to essentially be asking a question about (simple) stochastic integration.

Comment: @cardinal Indeed. It seems the OP created $Y= X+u$, approximated in some way the empirical density, and integrated it numerically ... twice? I wonder what that means. Did she integrated a constant in the second integration? Or maybe there is some confusion regarding the fact that there are two rv's involved and so one "should consider the joint distribution"?